# git: whether the pulled branch contains the latest changes from the `master` branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

The context of my question: I want the **Merge** button in the **Pull Request** form to be disabled *if the pulled branch being checked out does not contain the latest changes from the `master` branch*. I will use it in CI/CD.

Question: Is there any way to check it with the `git` utility?

Comment: Git does not have a "merge button", nor even pull requests in the first place, so whatever it is you're trying to enable/disable is in some IDE or on some web interface and not inherently part of Git itself. You need to update your question (and probably redirect it to, e.g., [tag:github] or [tag:bitbucket] instead of [tag:git]) appropriately.

Comment: @torek I know git not have a button. I explained context for clearity. My question is: how to do the check  through the git utility?

Comment: The details depend on the *rest of the system*. Nobody can answer—at least, not correctly—without those. It's like asking whether the cure for the illness is the drug that slows down the heart, or speeds up the heart. Depends on which illness you have!

Comment: just reworing torek's comment : what git service are you using ? github ? azure devops ? bitbucket ? ...

Comment: @LeGEC bitbucket.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you need to pull/rebase so that your feature branch has the latest changes from the remote main/master branch.